# xsl:template - How to render the page from right to left?

Tags: pdf, xsl-fo, right-to-left

I have `xsl:template` which is currently being rendered from `left to right`, and I wish to render it from `right to left`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    xmlns:report="http://caretalks.somecompanyname.com/IET/2007/12"
    xmlns:Parse="com.somecompanyname.caretalks.util.StringParserUtils"
    xmlns:Ext="com.somecompanyname.caretalks.util.XsltUtils"
    exclude-result-prefixes="fo">


    <xsl:template match="report:memberEngagementReport">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:fox="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions">
          <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simpleA" page-height="11in"
                    page-width="8.5in" margin-top="0.5cm" margin-bottom="0.5cm"
                    margin-right="0.5cm" margin-left="0.5cm"
                    writing-mode="{$writingMode}">
                <fo:region-body margin-top="1cm" margin-bottom="2.6cm"
                        margin-right="1.5cm" margin-left="1.5cm"/>
                <fo:region-before extent="0.5cm"/>
                <fo:region-after extent="2.0cm"/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
          </fo:layout-master-set>

    .
    .
    .
    .
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've searched the web for possible solutions and I couldn't find what I need.

What can I do in order to render it `right to left` ?

I'm also looking for approach to render it for both sides (LTR / RTL) and maintain one original `XSL` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`writing-mode` is inherited, so set `writing-mode="rl"` on `fo:root` for it to apply to the entire document.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#writing-mode.

You seem to be using FOP, so if you want the content of different regions to have different writing modes, you can't use `from-page-master-region()` to get the writing mode from the page region.  However, since you have a variable for the writing mode, you can set `writing-mode` on each `fo:flow` or `fo:static-content`.

Comment: Can you please give me an example how to set - fo:flow fo:static-content ?

Comment: That's a fairly open-ended question.  You will find lots of examples in other questions here on StackOverflow.  There's also an XSL-FO tutorial available at https://www.antennahouse.com/antenna1/xml-to-xsl-fo-stylesheets/ that you may find helpful.